# What is the proper notation for the composition of a relation and a function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus

Suppose I have a poset $(P, \leq)$ a function $f : P \to \{\text{Tomato}, \text{Potato}\}$.

Let $i, j \in P$. Is there a more compact way to write $(j \leq i) \land (f(j) = \text{Potato})$?

Comment: Just a question. You want to say that is true for all $i,j$ in those conditions, or they simply exists, or... it need to be more clear than that

Comment: Neither. I only want a more compact notation for the hypothesis.

Comment: The statement is clear (assuming the context makes it clear what the $i$ and $j$ are). Often lots of notation and symbols can look intimidating but not actually convey the meaning any better than words. Possibly you could just say (depending on the context) "suppose that $j \leq i$ and that $f(j) = \text{Potato}$".